# serverless framework- shared code for python lamdas without layer or pip

Tags: python, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

I am trying to share some classes code between my lambdas in a serverless project that has several lambdas. I don't want to use layers to share the code as i want to iterate quickly over the shared code. Also i do not want to package my shared code in pip modules.

Is there any way to achieve this ? It seems so easy, so i am astonished there is no obvious documented solution for that beside using layers.

My preferred structure would be:

- lambda1

  - handly.py
- lambda2

  - handle.py
- common_code

  - shared.py

Comment: As far as I know if you don't pack functions separately serverless zip whole project and deploys it to all lambda functions.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to avoid `pip`? You could package the entire project as one module and just use different entry points in different lambdas.

Comment: @tripleee Thats what  i do. But how could i define shared code and import it in my lambdas? pip is too slow for sharing code.

Comment: "Slow" how? Rather sounds like your current deployment model is flawed. Maybe look into CI/CD automation.

Comment: @tripleee slow in the sense of rapid iteration over the shared code. still i think i am missing something